# How to align the table elements while content is dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on an online booking system. After the user books a ticket the page will redirect to a confirmation page.

The issue is that the hotel fare and cruise fare table elements are not aligning properly and content is dynamic. If I create a class for `<th>` that will be added to cruise also. Please help me on this

```html
<table class="flight-sum-tbl">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="package-title">
        Cruise - 7 nights Western Mediterranean - Norwegian: Epic
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="fare-title">Guest Information</th>
      <th class="alignleft fare-title width25">Cruise Fare</th>
      <th class="alignleft fare-title width25">Taxes</th>
      <th class="alignright fare-title">Total Due </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dashbdrbtm">
      <td>Mrs Anitha nagadasari</td>
      <td class="alignleft">$799.00</td>
      <td class="alignleft">$111.12</td>
      <td class="alignright">
        <span id="_ctl0_MainContentsPH__ctl0__ctl3__ctl0_GuestPriceList__ctl1_PaxtSubTotal">$910.12</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dashbdrbtm">
      <td>Ms Anitha test</td>
      <td class="alignleft">$799.00</td>
      <td class="alignleft">$111.12</td>
      <td class="alignright">
        <span id="_ctl0_MainContentsPH__ctl0__ctl3__ctl0_GuestPriceList__ctl2_PaxtSubTotal">$910.12</span>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="flight-sum-tbl">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4" class="package-title">
        Hotel - Exe Parc del VallÃ©s
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="fare-title">Room(s) Details</th>
      <th class="alignleft fare-title width25">Hotel Fare</th>
      <th class="alignright fare-title">Total Due </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="dashbdrbtm">
      <td>Room #1 Standard Room</td>
      <td class="alignleft">$59.51</td>
      <td class="alignright">
```

[image]

Comment: You need to either set the column width of both tables to be the same (ideally in CSS), or put all the data in a single table and use `colspan` where necessary

Comment: Sir, this booking system is developed using c# table structure is loading from backend

Comment: Ok, but that's not relevant to the problem. You simply need to amend the HTML or the CSS.

Comment: yes Sir,  I  have given  to display flex and display table  and display flex to the table but it's not aligning properly.

Comment: Please help to me to align table elements

Comment: You can add an empty column both `ROOM DETAILS` and `Room #1..` rows. Or you can add a tax column and make it zero.

Comment: Yes, Sir, I tried this also because the content is dynamic we cannot create the empty column. If we create empty column same empty column will display in cruise fare table also

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is right. Put everything in a single table is the easyest way to do it
The other way is to fix (hardcode it) width of column of your table. You can do it by overriding the table CSS